# How retrieve files that don't contain a certain string in their content using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, path, fs

I have an `array` of `strings` representing file `paths` in my `directory`. I have created a `function` called `readFileContent` to read a file's content & another `function` to find a certain `string` within the file's content. Now I want to create a new `array` of file paths that contain said `string`. However, I don't get it to work. This is my code:

```
const allFilePaths = [
  '/path/to/file1.js',
  '/slighty/longer/path/to/file2.js',
  '/way/slighty/longer/path/to/file3.js',
  '/path/to/file4.js',
];

// utility function to check if str param doesn't contains "https" string
const getUrl = str => !str.match(/https:\s*([^;]+)\n/);

// utility function to read a file - the file param represent a file path
const readFileContent = file => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(data);
    });
  });
};

(async () => {
  // functions to return all file that don't contain a url, I get error: str.match is not a function
  const allFileWithoutUrls = await str.match is not a function.map(file =>
    getUrl(readFileContent(file)) ? file : null
})();
```

What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `.filter` method instead of `.map`. The `.filter` method will return a new array with each item dependent on if you return a truthy or falsy value in the callback function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
const allFilePaths = [
  "/path/to/file1.js",
  "/slighty/longer/path/to/file2.js",
  "/way/slighty/longer/path/to/file3.js",
  "/path/to/file4.js",
];

// utility function to check if str param doesn't contains "https" string
const getUrl = (str) => !str.match(/https:\s*([^;]+)\n/);

// utility function to read a file - the file param represent a file path
const readFileContent = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(file, "utf8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(data);
    });
  });
};

(async () => {
  // functions to return all file that don't contain a url, I get error: str.match is not a function
  const promises = allFilePaths.map(async (filePath) => {
    const contents = await readFileContent(filePath);
    return { contents, filePath };
  });
  const contents = await Promise.all(promises);
  const allFileWithoutUrls = contents
    .filter(({ contents }) => getUrl(contents))
    .map(({ filePath }) => filePath);
  console.log(allFileWithoutUrls);
})();
```

Comment: I get all the files regardless if they have `https:` in their content or not, unfortunatel

Comment: You're right. The `.filter(async (filePath) =>` always returns true because it returns a promise. I updated the answer to work with that. If it's still not working, revise the `getUrl` function. I changed it to `const getUrl = (str) => !str.match(/https:/);` for my own tests.